# Clojure automatically require files

Tags: clojure

I am trying to make little web framework in clojure. I have a bunch of clojure files in /handlers directory and I want to require all of them in my project's .core namespace. Every file defines its own namespace. For example: project.handlers.home. The idea behind this is when I add new handler, I don't want to modify namespace declaration in my core file to include it. The only solution I came up is to find all files in directory and load them with clojure.core/load, but it is far from beautiful and idiomatic. Is there a idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Did try anything yet?

Comment: Nothing more than traversing directory and doing (clojure.core/load "file").

Comment: You should really show some effort in the question, that you did try something, and where exactly you are stuck. Usually you show some code. The *downvote* arrow says: "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I'm sure that you will get answers if you do that.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I hope question is more clear now.

Comment: @BrunoReis actually now that closing has been renamed to "on hold", you can vote to put a question question on hold for "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a idiomatic way to do this?

IMO, no. The idioms in Clojure usually favor being explicit over "doing magic", especially when it comes to naming global objects (which auto-loading namespaces clearly is).

I don't know why you wouldn't want to modify your "core" file when adding new handlers but you might consider introducing an additional namespace that loads both "core" and your handlers and hooks them together.

Answer (score 1):

[Noir](http://www.webnoir.org/) included [some functionality](http://www.webnoir.org/autodoc/1.2.1/noir.server-api.html#noir.server/load-views) like this, making it an explicit API call to load namespaces under a particular directory.  See [load-views](http://www.webnoir.org/autodoc/1.2.1/noir.server-api.html#noir.server/load-views) for an example of this.  It used this to auto-load paths.

However, the Noir approach didn't feel idiomatic due to the amount of magic involved, as well as additional complications from the approach (e.g. lingering path definitions).

If you need to find namespaces from a tooling, framework, or library perspective, I would use [`find-namespaces` in `tools.namespace`](http://clojure.github.io/tools.namespace/#clojure.tools.namespace.find/find-namespaces) and then require/load them.  This approach could be useful in terms of providing user level pluggability, where a user can drop a handler into a directory and then see new options in the code, though again being explicit tends to be significantly cleaner.