# How to make symbol(s) from namespace accessible in all namespaces w/o qualifier?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I have namespace with debug utilities that are used only in development. I'd like to make them accessible in all namespaces without qualifier (same as symbols from `clojure.core`).

Let's say my project structure is as follows:

*dbg_utils.clj*:

```
(ns project.dbg-utils)

(defmacro dbg ...)
```

*db.clj*

```
(ns project.db)

(defn create-entity [...]
  ...)
```

After I'd like to fire up REPL and type something like this:

```
> (require 'project.db)
> (require 'project.dbg-utils)
> (globalize-symbol 'project.dbg-utils/dbg)
```

And after use `dbg` macro without qualifier:

```
(ns project.db) ;; no require of project.dbg-utils

(defn create-entity [...]
  (dbg ...) ;; and no qualifier here
  ...)
```

Is anything like `globalize-symbol` (or close to this) available?

Comment: Do you want to do it without using `require` and/or `intern`?

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl probably I haven't formed my question well. Let me rephrase it a little bit.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl answering your question: yes, I'd like to access them without `require`'ing `dbg-utils` namespace.

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve: hassle to require such namespace everywhere or potential overhead of debug macros in production mode?

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl In your example `(ns project.db)`, what do you expect to happen with `dbg` if `globalize-symbol` hasn't been called?

Comment: @ciniglio exception should be thrown (unable to resolve symbol). the idea is to use `dbg` without qualifier only after calling `globalize-symbol`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clojure automatically require files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394342/clojure-automatically-require-files)

Comment: You can use leiningen's `:injections` feature and the `:user` profile for that. [This article](http://z.caudate.me/give-your-clojure-workflow-more-flow/) shares some pointers on how to do that. It basically works by adding the functions you want in all your namespaces to `clojure.core` since all its public vars are always included when using the `ns` macro.

Comment: @juan.facorro this seems to be exactly what I need. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leiningen provides the `:injections` feature and the `:user` profile for that.

[This article](http://z.caudate.me/give-your-clojure-workflow-more-flow/) shares some pointers on how to do that. It basically works by adding the debugging functions you want to `clojure.core` and since all public vars from this namespace are always included when using the `ns` macro (unless you specify otherwise), you will have them available in all your namespaces.