# Make clojure functions available in every namespace during development?

Tags: clojure

I have number of useful helper functions that I use at the REPL during Clojure development. This includes some built-in functions like `doc` and `pprint`, but also some custom ones of my own from my `user.clj`. The default clojure experience seems to be:

```
dev> (doc +)
;; works
dev> (in-ns 'project.core)
project.core> (doc +)
;; what is this "doc" thing you're talking about!?!?
```

which is pretty irritating (I'm aware that I can refer to `clojure.repl/doc` here). Is there an easy way to ensure that something is available during development regardless of which namespace I'm currently operating in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make symbol(s) from namespace accessible in all namespaces w/o qualifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414489/how-to-make-symbols-from-namespace-accessible-in-all-namespaces-w-o-qualifier)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add a `:repl-options` to your project map in `project.clj`:

```
(defproject myproj "1.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0-alpha15"]]
  :repl-options { :init-ns myproj.core
                  :init (require '[clojure.repl :refer :all]) })
```

...

```
$ lein repl
myproj.core=> (doc +)   ; works
```

Comment: The "init" code appears to only run on REPL startup, so the "require" calls don't happen if you switch to another namespace. I guess I'd need a hook which gets run whenever you switch namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

As [Alex Gherega](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43198820/440294) mentions, it's probably a bad idea to automatically and indiscriminately import stuff into every namespace.  However, you could create a macro (or maybe a function would work?) to help import development-related namespaced when/if they are needed.  Add it to your `user.clj`.  Then if you are working in another namespace and decide it would be useful, you can just run `(user/import-useful-dev-stuff)` (or whatever you decide to call it).

For what it's worth, I pretty much do all my REPL sessions within the `user` namespace and `require` all the namespaces I need from there.  I use Emacs, and if I need to change something in another namespace, I just change the source, then do `C-c C-k` (after initiating a cider session) to reload the file.  If you don't use Emacs, it's only a little more work to reload from the REPL via `require` with the `:reload` option.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use boot or lein or some other form that would "magically" add this namespace to your REPL development session then I'm afraid you're just have to require it by hand every time.

The thing is namespaces have their well intended role of avoiding name conflicts. If you would have another way of telling a current namespace to use/require another namespace without doing it then you would have a whole lot of other problems.

If you're not using lein/boot you could [just do as Alex Miller responded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197222/440294). For a more controlled way of what you need from the clojure.repl or some other ns API just have a `require` & `use` declaration in you namespace of interest e.g.:

```
(ns 'project.core
   (:require [clojure.repl :refer [doc]]))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you get yourself in this situation, do:

```
(clojure.core/refer-clojure)
```

to require and load everything from clojure.core.

---

Or an alternate approach, if `project.core` exists, is to instead:

```
(require 'project.core)
(in-ns 'project.core)
```

Loading the namespace via `require` will refer clojure.core.

---

Or if `project.core` does not exist, do:

```
(ns project.core)
```

The `ns` macro will do both `refer-clojure` and `in-ns`.

Comment: Sorry, this seems to be an approach for bringing in the symbols from the "clojure.core" namespace. What I am looking for is a way to automatically have things from *non-core* namespaces (e.g. "doc", "pprint", or my own custom function) be always present during REPL development.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I misunderstood. There is nothing in Clojure that provides this, but some tools have ad hoc support for it.